# How to launch an app using a deeplink in android

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want to launch app using my own app but not by giving the package name, I want to open a custom URL.

I do this to start an application.

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Instead of package name is it possible to give a deep-link for example:

```
"mobiledeeplinkingprojectdemo://product/123"
```

[Reference](http://mobiledeeplinking.org/)

Answer (score 27):

You need to define a activity that will subscribe to required intent filters:

```
<activity
    android:name="DeepLinkListener"
    android:exported="true" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />      
        <data
            android:host="host"
            android:pathPattern="some regex"
            android:scheme="scheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then in `onCreate` of your `DeepLinkListener` activity you can access the host, scheme etc.:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent deepLinkingIntent= getIntent();
    deepLinkingIntent.getScheme();
    deepLinkingIntent.getData().getPath();
}
```

Perform check on path and again fire a `Intent` to take the user to corresponding activity. Refer data [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) for more help.

Now fire a `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(DEEP_LINK_URL));
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but is there a way doing it without specifying anything in the xml file and also what is this deepLinkingIntent ?

Comment: If you know the activity to launch then why don't you launch it via intent directly?

Comment: This answer is addressing the opposite of the question.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to handle the exception. If there is no activity that can handle the deep link, startActivity will return an exception.

```
    try {
    context.startActivity(
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            data = Uri.parse(deepLink)
        }
    )
} catch (exception: Exception) {
    Toast.makeText(context, exception.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```